# Item command doesn't recognise the items Spigot

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I am developing a spigot plugin for fun and it has a couple items. I tried making an item command so that I can get the items easier.

```
public class giveCommand implements CommandExecutor {

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {

        if (!(sender instanceof Player )) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You must be a player to run this command!");
            return true;
        }

        final Player player = (Player) sender;

        if (args.length < 1) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify the item you want!");
            return true;
        } else if (args.length > 1) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Too many arguments!");
            return true;
        } else if (args.length == 1) {
            if (args[0] == "wand") {
                player.getInventory().addItem(itemManager.wand);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You have been given a " + itemManager.wand.getItemMeta().getDisplayName() + ChatColor.GREEN + "!");
            } else if (args[0] == "powerstick") {
                player.getInventory().addItem(itemManager.powerStick);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You have been given a " + itemManager.powerStick.getItemMeta().getDisplayName() + ChatColor.GREEN + "!");
            } else if (!(args[0] == "wand" || args[0] == "powerstick")) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "That item doesn't exist!");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Every time I run `/i wand` or `/i powerstick`, it just says invalid items. The fix and any improvements to easily add future items would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your if statements. You should not check a string with `==` but with String#equals(anotherString) or with String#equalsIgnoreCase(anotherString)

String#equalsIgnoreCase(..) simply ignores the caps.

Try :

```
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("wand")) {
                player.getInventory().addItem(itemManager.wand);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You have been given a " + itemManager.wand.getItemMeta().getDisplayName() + ChatColor.GREEN + "!");
            } else if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("powerstick")) {
                player.getInventory().addItem(itemManager.powerStick);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You have been given a " + itemManager.powerStick.getItemMeta().getDisplayName() + ChatColor.GREEN + "!");
            } else if (!(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("wand") || args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("powerstick"))) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "That item doesn't exist!");
            }
```